# Places Web Service API, filter by country. Not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm using the Google Places Web Service API to query places serverside as documented here:

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

According to the docs it should be possible to filter the results by country via parameter 'components=country:SE'.

However when querying like below the filtering doesn't seem to work. The resultset contains both entries from Sweden and other countries.

What am I doing wrong here, any idea?

Example REST query

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/queryautocomplete/json?input=sto&components=country:SE&key=[YOUR-API-KEY-HERE]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running a [**QueryAutocomplete**-request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/query?hl=en)(where the components-parameter isn't available), but the linked documentation is for **PlacesAutocomplete**-requests.

With a **PlacesAutocomplete**-request you would get the desired result(limited to sweden )

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=sto&components=country:SE&key=[YOUR-API-KEY-HERE]

Comment: A slightly subtle difference! This was the exact issue for me.